# Duplicate iteration in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I am having 3 docx in a directory. `abcd.docx`, `uvwx.docx`, `qwer.docx`. I am iterating through these files. Here I am getting an additional iteration in which the last iteration prints `er.docx`. i.e. it skips the first two characters and prints the rest of last file. Below is the code and output.

```
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".docx"): 
        print(os.path.join(directory, filename))
```

Output:

```
filepath\abcd.docx     
filepath\uvwx.docx
filepath\qwer.docx
filepath\er.docx
```

Why this last iteration happens?

Comment: Is this batch-file really?

Comment: This is python, how did you come up with a `batch-file` tag?

Comment: @double-beep sorry. i changed it

Comment: @GerhardBarnard sorry i changed it

Comment: I'm surprised that your for loop prints anything since it's not properly indented.

Comment: what are you passing in `directory`?

Comment: Please don't add specific-version tags to your posts. These are added if code is working in specific version and so on. Also, don't add continuous spaces to your post. This is called vandalism/

Comment: There's nothing in your code that would show this behaviour: you're likely to have an actual `er.docx` file in that directory.